# Access com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay ? Attach Source

Tags: android

I got this error.

```
05-18 13:15:16.450: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.populate(ItemizedOverlay.java:311)
```

Can I access this code so I can see what went wrong? Where is com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay ?

I find it in Eclipse in Package Explorer:

```
Google APIs [Android 2.2] -> maps.jar -> com.google.android.maps -> ItemizedOverlay.class
```

but then it says Source not found... You can attach the source by clicking Attach Source below:

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly not, the mapview isn't open source so you have no access to it (hence why 'android' and android with 'google APIs' are different target platforms.  The former is open source, the latter adds in the closed source google APIs such as google maps).

Post your code so we can have a look.

Comment: Here is another question which I posted which  had this error.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653938/adding-custom-index-to-arraylist-or-sortedmap-when-adding-overlayitem-to-itemize